# Retaining session data only if browser is closed by mistake in java

Tags: java

How can we maintain data in session when browser is closed abruptly by mistake. And not store data every time when we open the session.

Comment: How do you expect to tell the difference between mistake and intent?

Comment: Sorry I meant if browser is closed in between an operation, say of the customer is adding items to cart and browser is closed, how can I keep the cart with items when next time user logs on.